# Bash : ambiguous redirect

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, command-substitution

I am trying to collect dump of Java process with jstack and I have tried below command. But it's saying `ambiguous redirect` as I can't redirect to a command.

```
 jstack -l `pgrep java` > /tmp/TD_`hostname`_`date`_`pgrep java`
-bash: /tmp/TD_`hostname`_`date`_`pgrep java`: ambiguous redirect
```

Is there any work-around I can achieve taking threaddump in a single line command with date and Java PID attached to threaddump file name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command substitution output probably has spaces, leading to field splitting, etc. Use quotes:

```
$ echo foo > /tmp/TD_`hostname`_`date`_`pgrep java`
bash: /tmp/TD_`hostname`_`date`_`pgrep java`: ambiguous redirect
$ echo foo > /tmp/"TD_`hostname`_`date`_`pgrep java`"
$ ls /tmp/TD*
/tmp/TD_muru-arch_Sat 26 Dec 16:14:29 IST 2015_
```

Comment: you are awesome , how did I miss that ?

Comment: it might be worth noting that `bash`'s `$IFS` splitting for the `<>` redirection target word is nonstandard and wouldn't occur in a POSIX shell.

Comment: @mikeserv, POSIX allows that behaviour for interactive shells. When non-interactive, bash doesn't do it when called as `sh`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - it does do it in the script though as `bash`. quoting redirects annoys me, but i do it for `bash`'s sake.

Comment: @mikeserv, agreed. Same here. You could do it as well for ksh and yash sake though, as code sourced from interactive ksh or yash would also need the quoting (for the glob part).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - point taken - but i usually do what i mean in an interactive shell - or am just testing in a chroot or something. i want the scripts to *work*.